# Compressing RGB images with numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, rgb

I have 10,000 images in RGB in an ndarray the size of (10000, 32, 32, 3).
I'd like to efficiently compress the images (take the means of colors) to 2x2, 4x4 etc. using `numpy`. The only idea I've got so far is to manually split the images, compress, and put together the pieces within the loops. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I *think* that you can do what you what with `scipy.ndimage.mean`

Comment: If I understand what you want to do (resize the images in dimensions 1 and 2 only) then `scipy.ndimage.zoom()` lets you use different scale factors along different dimensions.

Comment: So you want the output shape to be i.e. `(10000, 8, 8, 3)` for 4x4 interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, using [`scipy.ndimage.zoom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as si

def resample(img, dims):
    orig = img.shape[1]

    new_imgs = []
    for dim in dims:
        factor = dim / orig
        new_img = si.zoom(img, zoom=[1, factor, factor, 1])
        new_imgs.append(new_img)

    return new_imgs
```

For example, with random data:

```
>>> img = np.random.random((100, 32, 32, 3))
>>> resample(img, dims = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32])
>>> [img.shape for img in new_imgs]
[(100, 2, 2, 3),
(100, 4, 4, 3),
(100, 8, 8, 3),
(100, 16, 16, 3),
(100, 32, 32, 3)]
```

Note from the comment (below) that you might need to adjust the `mode` parameter in the `zoom` function.

Comment: The code is exactly what I need. However, I noticed `si.zoom` function with `dims = 16` produces different results. The pixels on two edges turn black for some reason. I set `mode` parameter to "nearest" and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SciKit image's `view_as_blocks` and `np.mean()`:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage

images = np.random.rand(10000, 32, 32, 3)
images_rescaled = skimage.util.view_as_blocks(images, (1, 4, 4, 1)).mean(axis=(-2, -3)).squeeze()
images_rescaled.shape
# (10000, 8, 8, 3)
```